# Memory leak in Node/Express/Request

Tags: node.js, express

Ever since we added this code to check whether our API could contact another service the memory, as recorded through AWS, has been steadily increasing until the container gets ejected and restarted. Over a six day period it went up to 600% of its previous stable state, restarted and did exactly the same. It has done that 4 times in a row at exactly the same rate. The API gets used at different rates through out the day, but the health check requests are at a constant rate.

The intention is to use this as a simple 'canary in the coal-mine', so that if we see our API can no longer reach the other service we know any genuine data requests are going to fail

```
const request = require('basic-request');
```

...

```
app.get( '/healthcheck', ( req, res ) => {

  request.getResponse('https://' + process.env.UVAPI_ECO_HOST + ':' + process.env.UVAPI_ECO_PORT + '/rest/api/swagger.json',
'GET', null, (error: string, response: any) => {
    res.send({
        build:  process.env.ORIGINAL_BUILD_NUMBER,
        deploy:  process.env.DEPLOY_NUMBER,
        hash:  process.env.GIT_COMMIT,
        hostname:  process.env.hostname,
        service_status:  {
            ecoconnect: (error || String(response.statusCode) !== '200') ? 'failed' : 'ok'
            },
        tracking_id:  process.env.TRACKING_ID,
        version:  process.env.VERSION
    });
  });
} );
```

Previously it would build a the object out of *process.env.______* values and then *res.send* it back. It's only once we started using *request.getResponse* that the memory started accumulating.

Comment: May I ask you why you're using `basic-request`? It doesn't look like a widely used module and might very well be the cause of memory leaks you're experiencing.

Comment: It was just the one a team mate looked up when finding out how to make a request in Express. What's the more common method?

Comment: [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) are pretty popular in Node.js development. The former aims to be consistent with the browser's [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), the latter is arguably easier to use and tends to be more concise for basic requests.